# HTML tag attributes disappearing with NSURLSession

Tags: html, ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an iPhone-app that downloads certain pages of a website from my work-website with `NSURLSession`. I then parse the webpage with `NSXMLParser` and display the information I get in a TableView. I know HTML is not XML but `NSXMLParser` does a good job and is simple to use. This was working just fine up until a few days ago when our IT-department did an update to their systems. Trying to find out what is going wrong it seems my code is actually still working fine but the problem is that some of the HTML-attributes I need are not seen anymore by `NSURLSession`.

This is the code I use to download the webpage:

```
func loadPage(linkToFollow: String) {
    // make NSURLSession task
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: linkToFollow)!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.allowsCellularAccess = true
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    let task: NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data : NSData?, response : NSURLResponse?, error : NSError?) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!.description)
        } else {

            // make string of data and log
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
            print("\nDATASTRING:\n")
            print(dataString)

            // data directly to an NSXMLParser
            let myParser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            myParser.delegate = self
            myParser.parse()
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

In a browser the page looks the same as before. Looking at the source code in Safari (same result in Firefox and Chrome):

```
<td class="TableCellContent"><input name="txtReisNummer_Weergave" type="text" value="R2015-065707" readonly="readonly" id="txtReisNummer_Weergave" class="TextBoxNormal" style="width:400px;" /></td>
```

The attribute I need is the value-attribute: '**value="R2015-065707"'**.

When I turn the data `NSURLSession` downloads into a string (see above code) it looks like this:

```
<td class="TableCellContent"><input name="txtReisNummer_Weergave" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="txtReisNummer_Weergave" class="TextBoxNormal" /></td>
```

Two of the attributes have disappeared: the 'value' and 'style' attributes.

When I let the parser log a description of the attribute dictionary I get this:

```
attributeDict, description = ["name": "txtReisNummer_Weergave", "type": "text", "id": "txtReisNummer_Weergave", "class": "TextBoxNormal", "readonly": "readonly"]
```

This gives the same result as logging the data-string, the 'value' and 'style' attributes are gone.

So what I need to know is why are the two attributes that are in the source code neglected by NSURLSession? And what can I do to rectify this so I can get the data I need?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Might be obvious, but did you clear the browser cache?

Comment: I don't have an answer but a workaround. You could have a PHP or other server-side file that parses the website and finds the pieces you need, and then the app calls on that file instead of directly to the website. I use this to parse HTML and it works. In fact, it might work to pass the entire html code that way as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Yedy, the problem occurs with an app running on an iPhone, and I don't know of a cache I should deal with using NSURLSession?

Comment: @Tim, thanks for your suggestion. Just to be clear, I don't have acces to the server the website is hosted on, so that would mean getting a server of my own up and running and doing what you suggest. I'll keep it in mind, but at this point I'm hoping for someone to explain to me why NSURLSession does what it does, and if there maybe is a setting that could change it's behavior.

Comment: I don't believe that NSURLSession is eating tags. So checking the servers output would be my first choice. Is the server still delivering the tags -> maybe the tags are only present in the browsers cache. Next check would be: is the server delivering different content for mobile -> check in Safari. Then I would try out the response with NSURLConnection to see if there might be a difference

Comment: @Yedy. I don't really understand your point about the browsers cache. I am not using any browser, so do you mean NSURLSession is caching? And if so how do I deal with that? I have reset the simulator and cleaned the app, no change in the result. The content delivery is the same for desktop and mobile, I checked. I tried NSURLConnection and it is giving the exact same result as NSURLSession. The attributes are gone. Safari is displaying the webpage as normal on desktop and mobile, including the content that is disappearing in Xcode.